# ¿como puedo usar especificadiones de formato en cout con c++?

Tags: c++

hola conozco algo de c y estoy aprendiendo c++

al querer formatear la salida tal como hacia en c

me he dado cuenta que desconozco la forma de hacerlo en c++

```
// como poner especificadores de formato en c++

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void){

   int num=2;

   // como obtener la misma salida de printf de c
   printf("\nel numero %d con ceros es: %04d\n\n", num, num);
   // salida: el numero 2 con ceros es: 0002

   // en c++
   cout <<endl<<"el numero "<<num<<" con ceros es: "<< num <<endl<<endl;
   // salida: el numero 2 con ceros es: 2

   cin.get();
   return 0;
}
```

saludos y gracias por su tiempo